# What's the Object equivalent to an Array position in jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

The jQuery UI Dialog widget has a [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) option that can be an Object, String, or Array (with the String & Array forms deprecated).  The Array can contain an x, y coordinate pair in pixel offset from the top left corner of the viewport.  I'm not clear on what the Object equivalent of that is.  The Object examples in the [position documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) use strings like "left" or "center", not pixel coordinates.

How would you write

```
position: [42, 80]
```

using the Object notation?

Comment: From the API entry you linked: 'You can refer to the [jQuery UI Position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) utility for more details about the various options.'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I read that documentation, but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: @cjm it's not the answer he is helping with comment. :P

Comment: It does. But put simply, you can't specify absolute co-ords when using object notation. Only alignments of the specific elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify an offset for the position option using object notation.

```
$('.selector').dialog({ position: { my: 'left+42 top+80', at: 'left+42 top+80' } });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rknjG/

Comment: That isn't equivalent.  Try changing it to `[42,80]`, hit Run, and see the dialog move.

Comment: It looks like `{ my: 'left top', at: 'left+42 top+80' }` works, though.  I'm not sure what happens if the window has scrolled; jsfiddle doesn't let you try that.

Comment: @cjm Right.  I noticed that if you halve the values, it works as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/rknjG/1/